# Remove reoccurrences from the table using SQL

Tags: sql

I have simple SQL table with 4 columns. They are: staff_id_1, building_id_1, staff_id_1 and staff_id_2. The problem is:

```
| 1 | 4 | 6 | 2 |  
...  
| 6 | 2 | 1 | 4 |
```

every four numbers that appears in the table also appears in it in mirrored (like in the example). Every row has its own mirrored "twin". I need to delete from the table one row from each pair of mirrored fours. So e.g. in the example above only | 1 | 4 | 6 | 2 | row should remain.

Comment: I can't tell what the column names really are.

Answer (score 1):

If all rows are mirrored, you should be able to do:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.col1 < t.col3;
```

I suspect in your query this would be:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.staff_id_1 < t.staff_id_2;
```

but your column names don't make sense in (at least the original version of) the question.